# Iterate an array n times at a time in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 12 elements and i need to display 4 items at a time.This is what i have

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    0 => "ed",
    1 => "smith.co.uk",
    2 => "http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg",
    3 => "Published",
    4 => "ford attenborough",
    5 => "ford.co.uk",
    6 => "http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg",
    7 => "Pending Approval",
    8 => "greg tolkenworth",
    9 => "greg.co.uk",
    10 => "http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg",
    11 => "In Future"
);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
echo $value."---".$value."---".$value."---".$value."<br/><hr/>";
}
?>
```

I need to display the values of the array `4` at a time or `3` at a time.

Comment: That will show the same value four times, you need to take 4 values, show them, skip 4 values, repeat.

Comment: Do you want to randomize the output, or you want to show 1-4, 5-8, 9-12 etc?

Comment: By skipping you mean,this values will be left out completely?.

Comment: @Mr.Alien i am not sure what you mean by randomizing but yes,i need to show if its 3 at a time yes or if its 4 at a time ,that still would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the array,

```
$newarray = array_chunk($array, 4);
```

Now `$newarray` has array of arrays having 4 items in each. like this,

```
$newarray = Array(
  0 => Array( 
    0 => "ed",
    1 => "smith.co.uk",
    2 => "http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg",
    3 => "Published"
   ),
  1 => Array(
    0 => "ford attenborough",
    1 => "ford.co.uk",
    2 => "http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg",
    3 => "Pending Approval"
   ),
 2 => Array(
    0 => "greg tolkenworth",
    1 => "greg.co.uk",
    2 => "http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg",
    3 => "In Future"
   )
);
```

Now you can run a `foreach` on `$newarray` to print 4 items at a time.

```
foreach($newarray as $arr){
  foreach($arr as $a){
   echo $a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Say i now want to show the values of the first set of array,will i have 4 foreach statements?.

Comment: Here is my code `$newarray = array_chunk($array,3);
foreach($newarray as $arr){
  foreach($arr as $a){
  }
  echo "---".$arr[0]."---".$arr[1]."---".$arr[2];
  echo "<br/><hr/>";
}`

Comment: @javamq If you want to hard code inner array indexes, ie., by doing `$arr[0]."---".$arr[1]."---".$arr[2];` then you don't need the inner foreach, you can remove `foreach($arr as $a){   } ` part.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_splice()](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-splice.php).
See the example below:

```
<?php
$array = Array
(
    0 => "ed",
    1 => "smith.co.uk",
    2 => "http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg",
    3 => "Published",
    4 => "ford attenborough",
    5 => "ford.co.uk",
    6 => "http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg",
    7 => "Pending Approval",
    8 => "greg tolkenworth",
    9 => "greg.co.uk",
    10 => "http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg",
    11 => "In Future"
);

while(!empty($array)) {
    $partial = array_splice($array, $i, 4);
    print_r($partial);
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/Vthu4W) is the example executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    0 => "ed",
    1 => "smith.co.uk",
    2 => "http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg",
    3 => "Published",
    4 => "ford attenborough",
    5 => "ford.co.uk",
    6 => "http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg",
    7 => "Pending Approval",
    8 => "greg tolkenworth",
    9 => "greg.co.uk",
    10 => "http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg",
    11 => "In Future"
);
$i=0;
while($i < count($array)) { 
    echo $array[$i]."---".$array[$i+1]."---".$array[$i+2]."---".$array[$i+3]."<br/><hr/>";
    $i+=4;
  }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is little tricky but working code

```
$array = Array
(
    0 => "ed",
    1 => "smith.co.uk",
    2 => "http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg",
    3 => "Published",
    4 => "ford attenborough",
    5 => "ford.co.uk",
    6 => "http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg",
    7 => "Pending Approval",
    8 => "greg tolkenworth",
    9 => "greg.co.uk",
    10 => "http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg",
    11 => "In Future"
);
$val = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if($key > 0 && $key <= 3){
        continue;
    }
        $val .= $value . " =|= ";

    if(($key+1) % 4 == 0){
        echo $val."<br/><hr/>";
        $val = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks neat.What if i wanted in the first 4,to show only the first item i.e in the array show only ed , what can be done?.